# Output status messages to the console from cypher neo4j-shell

Tags: shell, neo4j, console, cypher

I'm running some Neo4j cypher queries using `neo4j-shell`. They have long execution times as I am importing large CSV files.

I would like to output some messages to the console as each stage of the import completes, so that we can see the import progress at run-time without having to wait for the execution to complete.

I've checked the Cypher RefCard and can't find an example of this. Does cypher support outputting to the shell console window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Return" string is printed twice since the first is the header, and the second is the content. You can use "AS" with backticks to change the header to make it look better:

```
MATCH (n) 
DETACH DELETE n;
RETURN "Existing data removed" AS `Action:`;
```

Even better, you can combine the operation output with the message:

```
MATCH (n) 
DETACH DELETE n
RETURN count(n) AS `Existing data removed:`;
```

Comment: I like this approach. Simple and easy.

Answer (score 3):

I find it a really interesting topic. IMO the best way to achieve it in a powerful way is to write a server plugin :

- You create a TransactionEventHandler that implements the [TransactionEventHandler interface](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html)
- You receive a [TransactionData](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionData.html) which represents what has been changed during the transaction
- You can transform the changes into json
- and finally write them to the logs
- activate the logs in the appenders

Answer (score 1):

hmm... ok.  you can put RETURN statements to give you a clue e.g.

```
load cvs with headers from 'file1.csv'
return 'file1'
load cvs with headers from 'file2.csv'
return 'file2'
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using `RETURN`. But each `RETURN` value is printed twice!
Not sure what exactly is happening there. But for debugging that is fine.

```
RETURN "Removing existing data...";
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n;
RETURN "Existing data removed";
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be great, but I don't think it's possible.  In the past I've resorted to counting the number of cypher queries and then counting the number of success messages in the terminal (ugh ;)

You're best bet is probably to write a script which pipes the cypher queries to the shell one-by-one and outputs in between.

(also, you may have this covered, but to help with slow imports remember to create appropriate indexes and [avoid the eager](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/)!)

Comment: ugh.  this is what I have to do as well.  can it really be that dumb?  still looking for a solution!